# How to close modal after click on submition button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bpopup

How to close modal after clicking on submit button? I using bPopup plugin.

Thank you :)

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="popup" style="display: none;">
    <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
<input type="email" value="" placeholder="email" name="EMAIL" class="required email  border-color1 color1" id="mce-EMAIL">
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="sign up" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </div>
</div>

    $(function(){
    $('#pop').click(function(){
        $('#popup').bPopup();
    });
});

 setTimeout(function(){
    $('#popup').bPopup({
        modalClose: true,
        positionStyle: 'fixed' //'fixed' or 'absolute'
    });
    },3000);
```

Comment: `$("#mc-embedded-subscribe).onclick = function () {$('#popup').style.display = "none";}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function closePop() { $(selector).bPopup().close() }

parent.closePop();
```